# Connection for label/image view outlet for collectionViewCell not populating. ( no errors)

Tags: uicollectionview, connection, cell, outlet

I am trying to connect a label and image view outlet for a collection view cell with **control drag**, since each photo and label will be different. I have already done this before with a previous view controller. However this time when I try to get the outlets to connect to the cell class. It is not populating. Is there any reason why this is happening?

I also want to note that this view controller will be connected to another view controller I previously made that also uses a collection view. Could this be the reason why I am having this problem? I already created another view controller class and connected the collection view datasource and delegates. I also tried connecting the label and image view to my other collection view cell class that worked for the other collection view cell and it won't even populate there.

**Worked fine with my first collection view**

[image]

**When I drag it doesn't populate outlet connection**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, so I forgot to set the actual cells custom class property.

That fixed it.